# cuda-gdb giving error "warning: Cuda API error detected: cudaLaunchKernel returned (0x7)"

Tags: c++, cuda, nvcc, cuda-gdb

I am trying to debug a program in cuda-gdb. I am able to successfully set breakpoints in code that runs on the host (CPU), but whenever I try to set a breakpoint in code that runs on the GPU, the debugger skips over the breakpoints and gives me the following error:

```
"warning: Cuda API error detected: cudaLaunchKernel returned (0x7)"
```

It then continues to successfully execute the rest of the code. How can I make these work?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get the breakpoints to work based on [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1049119/cuda-programming-and-performance/debug-of-shared-memory-with-cuda-gdb/) answer from NVIDIA dev forums. Namely, in the nvcc compiler options you need to limit the amount of registers used by using the `maxrregcount` flag, e.g:

```
nvcc -arch sm_60 -g -G -dc --maxrregcount=64 --compiler-options -Wall -std=c++14 basic.cu
```

(Note: to see how much registers you have, enter `info cuda devices` into cuda-gdb and check the `Regs/Lane` column)

Comment: I get "No Cuda devices" although `nvcc --version` shows correct output and I can compile and run, just not debug.